# MySQL doest not use indexes on subquery (exists)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, correlated-subquery

why does MySQL not use the (expected) indexes when I query with a subquery (`exists`)?
I also tried it with an `JOIN` but happens the same, that MySQL does not use the indexes.
How can I improve this?
Query 1 does not use the (expected) indexes (users_uuid_unique, users_email_unique, first_name_I1, last_name_I1), they are just listed as possible
Query 2 does use the index (users_uuid_unique, users_email_unique)

Or does MySQL uses the correct indexes but does not list them in the `EXPLAIN` results?

Table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_uuid_unique` (`uuid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `user_data` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_data_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `first_name_I1` (`first_name`),
  KEY `last_name_I1` (`last_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_data_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Query 1:

```sql
desc select * from `users` where 
    (
    `uuid` LIKE 'oliver%' or 
    `email` LIKE 'oliver%'
    or exists (select * from `user_data` where `users`.`id` = `user_data`.`user_id` and `first_name` LIKE 'oliver%') or 
    exists (select * from `user_data` where `users`.`id` = `user_data`.`user_id` and `last_name` LIKE 'oliver%')
    )
order by `users`.`email` desc\G
```

Result:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: users
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: users_uuid_unique,users_email_unique
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 35
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: user_data
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: user_data_user_id_foreign,last_name_I1
          key: user_data_user_id_foreign
      key_len: 8
          ref: users.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 5.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: user_data
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: user_data_user_id_foreign,first_name_I1
          key: user_data_user_id_foreign
      key_len: 8
          ref: users.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 11.76
        Extra: Using where
3 rows in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Query 2:

```
desc select * from `users` where 
    (
        `uuid` LIKE 'oliver%' or 
        `email` LIKE 'oliver%'
    )
order by `users`.`email` desc\G
```

Result:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: users
   partitions: NULL
         type: index_merge
possible_keys: users_uuid_unique,users_email_unique
          key: users_uuid_unique,users_email_unique
      key_len: 144,1022
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using sort_union(users_uuid_unique,users_email_unique); Using where; Using filesort
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: *How can I improve this?* maybe use `USE INDEX (...,...)` in main and subqueries https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring your query to get rid of the [correlated subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) may help. Correlated subqueries can baffle the query planner.

It looks like you want any `users` row where the `uuid`, `email`, `first_name`, or `last_name` matches your search term.

Let's start with a query to get the set of `users.id` values of the rows you want.

```sql
       select id from users where uuid LIKE 'oliver%'
       union
       select id from users where email LIKE 'oliver%'
       union
       select user_id from user_data where last_name LIKE 'oliver%'
       union
       select user_id from users where first_name LIKE 'oliver%'
```

This runs four separate fast single-table index lookups. With the indexes you have each lookup should run well.

Then, use that subquery's set of `id` values to get your details and order them.

```sql
select * 
  from users 
 where id IN (
       select id from users where uuid LIKE 'oliver%'
       union
       select id from users where email LIKE 'oliver%'
       union
       select user_id from user_data where last_name LIKE 'oliver%'
       union
       select user_id from users where first_name LIKE 'oliver%'
       )
 order by email desc
```

**Pro tip** Skip the backticks. They make it hard to read and write your queries, and they're only necessary where you use a reserved word for a table or column name.